# Managing consistent Webpack builds in DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

Within our company we build and release a lot through DevOps for .NET Core applications.

For these application our setup is to have a single pipeline that builds the artifact and then the release pipeline manages pushing this same artifact out through the various stages (test / uat / staging / live)

The advantages we see here is that the package is the same and it is just environment variables on the deployment target that allow for variation in how it runs such as different 3rd party endpoints, different database etc.

We are now looking to move a Vue.js application which is built using Webpack into DevOps for automating the builds and deployments too, but here is where we are in a conundrum.

We need to encapsulate the same variation in our solutions (different api, configs, etc), this is currently managed by doing npm run build:uat, npm run build:live etc.

This works fine, but means we would need to setup different builds for each environment and loose the reassurance the the package we have put out for UAT is consistent with the release we put out for Live.

Are there any best practises around managing builds like this?

Possible options I can see, although open to others:

1. Build test / uat / live at the same time and then selectively copy the right code for the right environment
2. Different builds for each release
3. Can we have a single artifact build and then swap out the configuration variable in some other way?

Any support or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up going down the following route. We would ideally have had a single build but as the build for each environment is done at the same time from the same npm install install etc I'm happy with this as a compromise.

```
trigger:
- release/*

variables:
- template: config/app-names.yml

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: 
    npm install
  displayName: 'npm install'

- script: 
    npm run build:test -- --vn "$(Build.SourceBranchName)" --n "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
  displayName: 'npm build test'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive test'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'dist/$(TestAppName)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: 'dist/test/$(TestAppName).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- script: 
    npm run build:acc -- --vn "$(Build.SourceBranchName)" --n "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
  displayName: 'npm build acc'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive acc'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'dist/$(AccAppName)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: 'dist/acc/$(AccAppName).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- script: 
    npm run build:live -- --vn "$(Build.SourceBranchName)" --n "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
  displayName: 'npm build live'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive live'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'dist/$(LiveAppName)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: 'dist/live/$(LiveAppName).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish test build'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dist/test/'
    ArtifactName: 'test'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish acc build'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dist/acc/'
    ArtifactName: 'acc'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish live build'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dist/live/'
    ArtifactName: 'live'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 should be the simplest solution to understand and operate.

Do not need to keep using a single artifact. **A release can be configured to trigger off of multiple artifact sources** (builds). Then simply combine multiple builds in one release.

You could  create a task which add a label to the current build if there is no other build running/queued.

Additionally add a tag condition for the release trigger.

More details please take a look at boindiil's answer in this link: [Combine multiple builds into one release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101025/combine-multiple-builds-into-one-release)

Comment: Thanks for your response @PatrickLu-MSFT, we've ended up running a single build that produces artifacts for each environment. Ideally I think option 3 would have been the best, but as we are building for the three environments at the same time I'm more happy that things like package version, etc will be consistent and the builds will be as close as possible to each other.

I appreaciate the time you took in answering and the link you sent through was an interesting read

Comment: @SimonTheGoat  Glad to know it. Always better when you fix it yourself. You could share your solution here as a reply and *mark it*. in case others  get stuck in the same situation.